# Delete blocks filled around a snowball after 5 seconds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Currently I'm trying to make a new gamemode but I want the wool that I create with this command:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /fill ~1 ~1 ~1 ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 wool 5 replace barrier 0
```

...to disappear after 5 seconds. How can I do that? Also I was wondering if it is possible to change the color of wool when you enter a certain area in a map. So that I can create areas that are themed with a certain color.

Comment: You want to make a new gamemode?

Comment: Hmm... If what you said didn't work, then I'm not sure...

Comment: For a new gamemod you should create a Minecraft mod

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to do
/testfor @e[type=Snowball]
Then a comparator going from it with the fill command. Then, more comparators which will fill that white thing back with what it was. Also, next to the first fill command block you can have a command block where ch will summon a zombie or something else, so the other fill command blocks block will execute that entity and fill back the block. This video might help you.
[The video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le-UjFVDHhA)